# how to generate chart get input from database table using php and google chart

Tags: php, mysql, charts, google-visualization

I want to generate chart for getting input from database table.  In the chart X-axis date and Y-axis spending hours.This will happen for following table rows having values. finally generate chart..
Now i want get value from table to generate the chart..
please check my code and help me...

thank you...

```
 database table below...
   --------------------------
       day        time_diff
   --------------------------
   2016-12-09     00:15:38
   2016-12-09     00:10:12
   2016-12-09     00:05:40
  ---------------------------
```

chart.php

```
 <?php
 $mysql =mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'chart');

 $result = $mysql->query('select * from clock');

 $rows = array();
 $table = array();
 $table['cols'] = array(

                array('label' => 'day', 'type' => 'date'),
                array('label' => 'time_diff', 'type' => 'time')

               );
               $rows = array();
while($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  
{
//assumes dates are in the format "yyyy-MM-dd"
$dateString = $r['day'];
$dateArray = explode('-', $dateString);
$year = $dateArray[0];
$month = $dateArray[1] - 1; // subtract 1 to convert to javascript's 0-indexed months
$day = $dateArray[2];

//echo $dateString."<br>";

// assumes time is in the format "hh:mm:ss"
$timeString = $r['time_diff'];
$timeArray = explode(':', $timeString);
$hours = $timeArray[0];
$minutes = $timeArray[1];
$seconds = $timeArray[2];

//echo $timeString;


  $temp = array();   
  $temp[] = array('v' => "date($year-$month-$day)");       
  $temp[] = array('v' => "time( $hours:$minutes:$seconds)");

  $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
  }
  $table['rows'] = $rows;

  $jsonTable = json_encode($table);
  print_r($jsonTable);

 //$jsonTable1 = new DateTime( date(strtotime($jsonTable) ));

 ?>

  <html>
  <head>
   <!--Load the Ajax API-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});

  // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
   google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);


   function drawChart()
   {
   var bar_chart_data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<?php echo $jsonTable1; ?>);

   var options = {
        title:"Company Performance",
        width:400,
        height:600,

               };
   var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

   chart.draw(bar_chart_data,options);
   }

  </script>
  </head>
        <body>
            <div id="chart_div"></div>
        </body>
    </html>
  </script>
  </head>
  </html>
```

i get output of this

```
{"cols":[{"label":"day","type":"date"},{"label":"time_diff","type":"time"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"date(2016,11,09)"},{"v":"time( 00,15,28)"}]},{"c":[{"v":"date(2016,11,10)"},{"v":"time( 03,05,00)"}]},{"c":[{"v":"date(2016,11,11)"},{"v":"time( 06,54,00)"}]},{"c":[{"v":"date(2016,11,14)"},{"v":"time( 00,00,02)"}]}]}
```

Comment: do u have any idea??? @Isaac Bennetch

Comment: No, I initially came here because of the phpmyadmin tag, but your question doesn't have anything to do with phpMyAdmin. I do suggest that you edit the question to show what results you're currently getting: is there an error message, wrong output, correct chart but it doesn't look right, etc. That will help other commenters to more easily see what the problem is. As it's written, it's difficult to understand how your intended output differs from the actual output.

Comment: okay..my output is above @Isaac Bennetch